# Is a black moon possible?

Tags: moons, minerals

I had an idea about a moon whose surface appears to be entirely covered by basalt and other volcanic minerals like obsidian giving the moon a black color. My question is: Is something like this possible and what would result in such a moon in the first place?

Note: I don't know if these are important details, but this moon is about 50% more massive than ours (Earth moon=1, Black moon=1.5) and despite the moon being covered in volcanic rocks it doesn't appear to have any volcanic or tectonic activity in the present.

Comment: There seem to be [dark gas giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrES-2b) but they are much bigger than the moon.

Comment: Related: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/217300/whats-the-darkest-lowest-albedo-rock-that-can-predominate-a-planets-surface

Answer (score 5):

Our moon is already black, or very dark gray. Its reflectivity compares to the one of asphalt, the same asphalt you see on the road.

And yes, it has also basalt over vast surfaces.

Comment: *Old* asphalt... For a visual impression, the Moon is roughly 12% grey, RGB(97, 97, 97) or #616161.

Answer (score 2):

**Dead Dinosaurs**

[image]

I can find no information on real black moons or rocky planets. There seem to be some [black gas giants](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2017/hubble-captures-blistering-pitch-black-planet/) but gas giants are much bigger than the Moon.

I suspect this is because basalt for example is a large complicated molecule and most planets are made of elements. Gas giants are made of Hydrogen and Helium. The Moon is mostly frozen oxygen and silicon.

So let's go with something stupid. The moon was once inhabited. It is no longer inhabited and all the bio-matter has died and turned into a layer of dead carbon on the surface. This oily layer of hydrocarbons makes the moon look black.

Comment: Actually petroleum is about as black as the actual Moon, quite often less black, and never much blacker. The Moon is about as black as old asphalt; it appears luminous only because it is illuminated by the Sun, which is a rather powerful light source. (And basalt is a rock, that is, a mixture of minerals. There is no such thing as a molecule of basalt.)

Comment: The moon is not "mostly frozen oxygen and silicon." All the solid objects in the solar system are covered in compounds of one kind of another, not pure elements.

Comment: @notovny What is the moon made of?

Comment: The [crust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geology_of_the_Moon#Elemental_composition) is mostly silica and alumina, with increasingly smaller portions of  lime, iron oxide, magnesia, titanium dioxide, and sodium oxide, a likely basaltic [mantle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_structure_of_the_Moon), and an iron alloy core. Silica is silicon dioxide, a compound composed of oxygen and silicon, but it is not "_frozen_ oxygen and silicon."

Answer (score 1):

*Option 1:*

A dwarf planet like Pluto might enter in a very eccentric orbit and pass so close to the sun that the surface would boil away leaving the rocky core exposed. Trouble is that in order to escape the gravitational pull of the sun the core must be quite fast. Before it could be captured like a moon it must be slowed down by another planet or a particular conjunction.

*Option 2:*

Does the moon have to be round? A head on collision between two large objects might leave around splinter fragments of the cores. Irregular and bumpy, but dark.

Answer (score 1):

## Only with geoengineering or in a far away moon

The earth moon is already mostly black, the sun is just so powerful it makes it look white.

To make it black it either needs to be too far away from the sun for life to flourish on a nearby planet, or it needs to be specifically engineered with a super dark material that overwhelms the light of the sun.